# Xamarin Android: Cannot create an android archive '' because the project does not have a package name

Tags: android, xamarin

XamarinAndroid newbie here:

Have you encountered this error when deploying an Xamarin Android app. This is in the archiving part.

Error:
"Cannot create an android archive '' because the project does not have a package name"

I've already posted a question in their forum but still waiting for response.

Comment: I seem to remember getting that before. I believe you need to set the name in the project property pages. If I recall correctly there is just a bogus placeholder there currently.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you mean I need to provide the "name" property on every activity in my xamarin android app?

Comment: No just once. Double click properties on the project level. Look through the tabs on the left. I don't remember which tab but it will be obvious when you hit the right one.

Comment: If this is what you mean:

Project Properties > Android Manifest.

The package name field already has a name provided but I still can't proceed with the archiving process.

Comment: Yes, that is it.   
Also make sure the naming convention is acceptable with android.

Here is a link also to help. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

Comment: You need to set the `package name` of your project in the Android options of your project. Once you've done this, build your project and ensure your generated `AndroidManifest.xml` found in the `obj/{CONFIGURATION}/android/AndroidManifest.xml` includes an `<manifest package="your.package.name">` element.

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks. Will take note of your reminder from the other forum :)

Comment: @Lorenz did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem but I clearly have a package name set and my manifest file has a package="". This was building file yesterday.

Comment: Has it been solved? Please, someone tell about any solution

Answer (score 3):

I started facing the same issue when I bumped up the version. I closed Visual Studio, removed Obj and Bin Folders. Created a new build and then archived; that solved my problem.

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by editing my .csproj file with this configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
 <Optimize>true</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
 <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
 <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
 <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
 <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
 <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
 <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
 <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
 <AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
 <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>true</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after renaming a project and under the Application properties I had used the same name for the Assembly Name and the Default Namespace and that seemed to cause this error. Renaming one of the values allow it to create the Archive ok

Answer (score 0):

If you use bundle package format set install location to Prefer Internal or Internal Only